# extracting CSV data

Tags: google-maps, csv, kml, tilemill

I am trying to build a custom map in Tile Mill and am new to programming in general so I apologize is if comes off as uninformed. I've done research but I'm not sure if I'm looking in the right place.

My basic question: this is an embedded map of restaurants in the SF area. Is there a way for me to extract the data for the locations to use in building a custom map of my own?

http://www.sfgate.com/food/top100/2012/map/

It seems that if the location markers exist on a map, that meta data is somewhere, I just don't know how/where to access it....I believe the raw formats for inputting location into a map are CSV or KML and wondering if there is a way to extra  these data types from embedded maps.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

View the source of the page in question, look for the data (it's under the variable `mapLocs`, copy it from the page, and write a little script to convert their format to CSV.

^ this is likely against at least 2 different copyrights (newspaper's & geocoder's), so proceed at your own risk.